# SharePoint migration 2010 to 2013, User Profile Mismatch/issue

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, 2016, migration

I have migrated SharePoint 2010 to 2013 and then 2013 to 2016 with Database restore method.

I am facing issue, We have unique permission in every list item. While checking I found that migrated list item user have `ABCDomain\nm002u` account name and when I add any user from SharePoint 2016 to permission page then it shows `i:0#.w|ABCDomain\nm002u` account name.

So, all views filtered with [Me] is not working and user cannot able to see any list item due to user profile mismatch.

How to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to migrate your users from Classic to Claims.  The easiest way to do this is with the Convert-SPWebApplication command in Powershell, or you can use the Move-SPUser command.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/upgrade-and-update/migrate-from-classic-mode-to-claims-based-authentication-in-sharepoint-2013